# Select next INPUT when checkbox is clicked inside same DIV

Tags: jquery

After many temptatives I still not manage the select the next `INPUT` to add a class to it when the checkbox (inside the same `DIV`) is checked. The expected result is:

checkbox is checked -> the class `auto-save` is added to the next `input` (the class is appended o `form-control`).

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <label class="checkbox-bootstrap checkbox-sm">
        <input class="save_data" id="save_title" type="checkbox" />
        <span class="checkbox-placeholder"></span>
    </label>
    <label for="title">Title (max 120 characters)</label>                           
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title" name="title" autocomplete="off" maxlength="120">
</div>
```

I **dont want** to use *class names* or *ids* as the code has many checkboxes and the class to add is always the same (`auto-save`) for every `INPUT`.

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).parent().next().find('input').addClass('auto-save');
}
else {
    $(this).parent().next().find('input').removeClass('auto-save');
}
```

Comment: `$(this).parent().parent().next().find('input').addClass('auto-save');` isn't it?

Comment: @Dammeul  `.next()` is not needed

Comment: Whoops... copy, paste and half concentration fail, have a vote up from me =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have change handler for checkboxes for adding and removing class in textbox based on checkbox checked state. You also have wrong selector to target textbox element. You need to traverse to closest div and then find text element in it.

Also you can reduce your code by using `.toggleClass()`:

```
 $('.save_data').change(function(){
      $(this).closest('div').find(':text').toggleClass('auto-save',this.checked);
 });
```

```js
$('.save_data').change(function(){
      $(this).closest('div').find(':text').toggleClass('auto-save',this.checked);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <label class="checkbox-bootstrap checkbox-sm">
        <input class="save_data" id="save_title" type="checkbox" />
        <span class="checkbox-placeholder"></span>
    </label>
    <label for="title">Title (max 120 characters)</label>                           
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title" name="title" autocomplete="off" maxlength="120">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need can try it

```
$('[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).closest('div').find('input[name="title"]').addClass('auto-save');
  }
  else {
      $(this).closest('div').find('input[name="title"]').removeClass('auto-save');
  }
});
```